# Angularjs use ng-options with filter without removing options from filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use a ng-options with a filter and the behavior seen is expected.  However, the expected behavior is not what is needed.

What would be the best practice when doing something like:

```
<div ng-init="blades = [{item:'1', spec:'2'}]"></div>
<select 
    ng-model="blades"
    ng-options="blade.spec as blade.spec for blade in blades">
    <option>--</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="blade in blades">{{blades.item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here, when you filter, you filter the values out of the select list rendering it useless.  What's the best practice?

Answer (score 5):

I answered my own question and a bunch of others in the process.  This is how :

```
<div ng-init="items = [{id:'1', spec:'A'}, {id:'2', spec:'B']"></div>
<select 
  ng-model="searchSpec"
  ng-options="item.spec as item.spec for item in items">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{spec:searchSpec}">{{item.spec}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a built-in way for doing this.  Make ng-model="search.spec" and search will always be {spec:(selectedValue)}.  It's nice, because you can tie multiple select dropdowns to different keys of the search object.

```
<div ng-init="items = [{id:'1', spec:'A'}, {id:'2', spec:'B']"></div>
<select 
  ng-model="search.spec"
  ng-options="item.spec as item.spec for item in items">
    <option>--</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">{{item.spec}}</li>
</ul>
```